# compare todays date with the date in the mysql table using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

i want to display an alert if the module expires by comparing todays date i.e if today's date is greater than end_date in mysql then an alert message should be displayed, but how do i compare the two?

my model code is as follows

```html
 function check_admin_login(){
   
   $this->db->where('username', trim($this->input->post('username')));
   $this->db->where('userpass ', sha1(trim($this->input->post('userpass'))));
   $this->db->where('status', '1');
   $this->db->where('deleted', '0');
   $this->db->select('*');
   $query = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users']);
   if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $row = $query->row();
    $this->db->where('userid', $row->id);
    $this->db->select('firstname,lastname,profileimage,company');
    $query1 = $this->db->get($this->myTables['users_details']);
    $row1 = $query1->row();
    $newdata = array(
         'is_admin_logged_in' => true,
         'admin_user_name' => $row->username,
         'admin_userpass' => $row->userpass,
         'admin_id'=>$row->id,
         'admin_lastlogin'=>date("d-m-Y H:i:s",$row->lastlogin),
         'admin_lastloginip'=>$row->lastloginip,
         'lastrefresh'=>time(),
         'company'=>$row1->company 
       );
       $company = $row1->company;
     $this->session->set_userdata($newdata); 
    $companyName = $this->session->userdata['company'];
   
    $this->update_admin_login_time($this->session->userdata('admin_id'));
    $this->admin_init_elements->set_global_user($row->username,$row->userpass);
    if($this->input->post('remember'))
    {
     $cookie = array('name'   => 'username','value'  => $row->username,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
     $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    }
    $name = $row1->firstname.' '.$row1->lastname;
    $cookie1 = array('name'   => 'name','value'  => $name,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie1); 
    $cookie2 = array('name'   => 'image','value'  => $row1->profileimage,'expire' =>  time()+7600,'secure' => false);
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie2); 
    
  $companyName = $companyName = $this->session->userdata('company');
  
   $otherdb = $this->load->database("$companyName", TRUE);

   
    $query1 = $this->db->query("Select * from pr_package");
    $today = new DateTime();
$compare = $today->format('Y-m-d');
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $this->db->where("end_date <", 
$compare);
   //$this->db->where('status','INACTIVE');
    if($query1->num_rows() > 0)
   {
    return 'inactive';
   }
   else
   {
    
     return 'Login Successful';
   }
  
  
   }else{
    return 'Incorrect Username or Password.';
   }
   
  }
```

My controller code is as follows:

```html
    function index(){
        //if Admin already logged in, send to Admin home
  
  $this->data['message']='';
  $this->data['msg_class'] = '';
  $post_array=$this->input->post();
  
  $data['old_images']=$this->mod_common->getBgImages();
  
  if($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on')
  {
   //echo $this->input->cookie('username');
   $this->data['message']=strip_tags($this->mod_login->check_cookie_login());
   if($this->data['message']=='Login Successful'){
    $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
     redirect('home');    
   }else{
    $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
   }
  } 
       if($this->input->post('action')=='adminLogin'){
  
  //print_r($this->input->post()); die;
    
   if(isset($post_array['remember'])){
    $username_cookie= array(
     'name'   => 'uusername',
     'value'  => $post_array['username'],
     'expire' => '865000',
     'secure' => FALSE
    );
    
    $password_cookie= array(
     'name'   => 'userpass',
     'value'  => $post_array['userpass'],
     'expire' => '865000',
     'secure' => FALSE
    );
    
    $remember_cookie= array(
     'name'   => 'remember',
     'value'  => 'on',
     'expire' => '865000',
     'secure' => FALSE
    );

    $this->input->set_cookie($username_cookie); 
    $this->input->set_cookie($password_cookie); 
    $this->input->set_cookie($remember_cookie); 
    //die;
    
   }
   else
   {
    if($this->input->cookie('remember') == 'on')
    {
     if($this->input->cookie('uusername') != $post_array['username'])
     {
      delete_cookie("remember");
      delete_cookie("uusername");
      delete_cookie("userpass");
     }
    } 
   }
   
   $this->data['message']=strip_tags($this->mod_login->validate_admin_login());
   if($this->data['message']=='Login Successful'){
    $this->data['msg_class'] = 'sukses';
     redirect('home');    
   }
   
   elseif($this->data['message']=='inactive')
   {
    
    echo '<script>alert("Inactive modules present in your system please Relogin")</script>';
    $this->index;
   }
   else{
    $this->data['msg_class'] = 'gagal';
   }
  } /*else if(isset()){
   
  }*/
  
  
 ///////////////////////
  $this->data['cookieRemember'] = $this->input->cookie('remember');
  $this->data['cookieUsername'] = $this->input->cookie('username');
  $this->data['cookiePassword'] = $this->input->cookie('userpass');
  //echo $this->data['cookieRemember'];echo $this->data['cookieUsername']; echo $this->data['cookiePassword'];
 //////////////////////
 
  $this->data['cookiename']  = $this->input->cookie('name', false);
  $this->data['cookieimage'] = $this->input->cookie('image', false);
  
  $sess_msg = $this->session->userdata('session_msg');
  $session_msg_class = $this->session->userdata('session_msg_class');
  if(isset($sess_msg) && $sess_msg!= ''){
   $this->data['message']=$sess_msg;
   $this->data['msg_class'] = $session_msg_class!=''?$session_msg_class:'gagal';
  }
        //render full layout, specific to this function
        $this->load->view('login', $this->data);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: is this solved ??

Answer (score 0):

Try using a DateTime object.

```
$today = new DateTime();
$compare = $today->format('Y-m-d');
```

Then in your WHERE clause it would be :

```
WHERE end_date < '$compare'
```

Let me know how you get on! :-)

Comment: this looks good, i am making a mistake here  $this->db->where("end_date <=", 
$compare);

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: Select * from pr_package" } ["query_times"]=> array(18) { [0]=> float(0.00095701217651367) [1]=> float(0.00075101852416992) [2]=> float(0.00282883644104) [3]=> float(0.00076794624328613) [4]=> float(0.00052213668823242) [5]=> float(0.00090885162353516) [6]=> float(0.0010490417480469) [7]=> float(0.0010261535644531) [8]=> float(0.0007481575012207) [9]=> float(0.00096511840820312) [10]=> float(0.00049591064453125) [11]=> float(0.00055313110351562) [12]=> float(0.00056695938110352) [13]=> float(0.00064301490783691) [14]=>

Comment: Thats not a query, thats a var_dump of an array!

Comment: Select * from pr_package

Comment: Where's the WHERE clause gone?